# The function $A:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $(n,x)\to nx$ is a group action on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I somehow came through this True or False question, but before answering it, I just wanted to ensure some things.

I understand that the axioms for $group-action$ must be met. Basically:

```
(Compatibility with identity): e∗x=x for all x∈X

(Compatibility with group operation): g1∗(g2∗x)=(g1∗g2)∗x,∀x∈X,g1,g2∈G.
```

where $*$ is the operation, $X$ the set and $G$ the group.

My question is, for the first axiom, the identity $e$ is obtained from the Group or from the set?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The identity comes from the group. The set doesn't necessarily have a group structure.

Comment: So, in this case, it would have to be $0$ ? Since $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition is the group, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a group action.

A group action of $G$ on a set $X$ is a map $G\times X\rightarrow X$ that satisfies a list of conditions, in particular, that $g_1.(g_2.x) = (g_1g_2).x$.

In your situation, take $n = 2$, $x = 1$, then the inverse of $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is $n^{-1} = -2$, but $n^{-1}.(n.x) = (-2)\cdot (2\cdot 1) = -4$, but $(n^{-1}n).x = (-2 + 2)\cdot 1 = 0$.

To answer your question though, a set doesn't come with the data of a distinguished "identity element". Here, you're considering $\mathbb{R}$ as a set, so you're completely forgetting about its group structure as far as the definition of your "action" is concerned.

Comment: Thank you. Another question though. So $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition is used, since $\mathbb{Z}$ under multiplication is not a group. Implying that the identity would have to be $0$ then, of which, under the first axiom, fails also?

Comment: yep that's true as well